# how to sort date object in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I want to sort array of objects.I have dates in my object I want to sort the dates of objects

I used this answer to solve my problem
[why array is not sorted in javascript in increasing date or decreasing date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695764/why-array-is-not-sorted-in-javascript-in-increasing-date-or-decreasing-date/33696030#33696030)

But when Used this solution it not work .

I make a ajax call and get data from server store in array .But data is **2000**  so it is difficult to check whether the data is sort or not .

So I will give you evidence that data is not sort .

- See object **7** value is **Thu Jul 24 2014**
- See object **10** value is **Mon Jul 28 2014**
- See object **67** value is  **Mon Apr 20 2015**
- See object **69** value is **Wed Dec 18 2013**

https://jsfiddle.net/rxaLutgn/6/

```
function sort_by(field, reverse, primer) {

            var key = primer ?
                function (x) {
                    return primer(x[field])
                } :
                function (x) {
                    return x[field]
                };

            reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;

            return function (a, b) {
                a = new Date(key(a)), b = new Date(key(b));
                return reverse * (a-b);
            }
        }
```

any update regarding this question.Below answer not working

Answer (score 0):

The function works fine if you are expecting all dates. Looking at your data there are some invalid dates like "-"

If you can't modify the data or expect a definite date always then you need to mod your function to do something like this (or handle it in some way to your liking)

```
function sort_by(field, reverse, primer) {

        var key = primer ?
            function (x) {
                return primer(x[field])
            } :
            function (x) {
                return x[field]
            };

        reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;

        return function (a, b) {
            a = new Date(key(a))=='Invalid Date'?0:new Date(key(a));
b = new Date(key(b))=='Invalid Date'?0:new Date(key(b));
            return reverse * (a-b);
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rxaLutgn/21/ <-- take a look here an plug in the objects that are badly sorted to limit the amount of data

Comment: it is not working please check https://jsfiddle.net/rxaLutgn/12/

Comment: please provide any fiddle

Comment: @user944513 if your fiddle is fixed to add back in the [`key(a)` and `key(b)`](https://jsfiddle.net/rxaLutgn/20/) calls it works.

Comment: As @binki pointed out there was a bug where I forgot to put in the key() back in the function. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, I did not include the primer like you did. But implementing it should be easy.

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3v7ya481187k8gf/a.json?dl=0",
}).done(function(data) {
    var arr;
    var _key =  "Expected_Payment_Date__c";//"akritiv__Promise_Date__c",
    var _reverse = true;
    arr=JSON.parse(data);
    arr.sort(function(a,b){
        var keyA = Date.parse(a[_key]);
        var keyB = Date.parse(b[_key]);
        var _rev = _reverse ? -1 : 1;

        if(keyA < keyB) return _rev * -1;
        if(keyA > keyB) return _rev * 1;
        return 0;
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```