# how sort works in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort my array having dates in objects present .I want to sort one property **“akritiv__Promise_Date__c”** using sort function  .I also asked one Question it’s answer is not working property 
[how to sort date object in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704493/how-to-sort-date-object-in-array)  .when I used it answer  it not sort my field

I make a ajax call and get data from server store in array .But data is **2000**  so it is difficult to check whether the data is sort or not .

So I will give you evidence that data is not sort .

- See object **7** value is **Thu Jul 24 2014**
- See object **10** value is **Mon Jul 28 2014**
- See object **67** value is  **Mon Apr 20 2015**
- See object **69** value is **Wed Dec 18 2013**

I want to to sort only one field

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/rxaLutgn/14/

```
function sort_by(field, reverse, primer) {

        var key = primer ?
            function (x) {
                return primer(x[field])
            } :
            function (x) {
                return x[field]
            };

        reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;

        return function (a, b) {
            a = new Date(a)=='Invalid Date'?0:new Date(a);
b = new Date(b)=='Invalid Date'?0:new Date(b);
            return reverse * (a-b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ask a similiar question yesterday?

Comment: why not sort it server side?

Comment: yes i asked this yesterday but it solution is not working

Comment: Why are you making the function so complicated, if you want to sort it you can write a much simpler function.

Comment: how ..could you please help how i will sort this property ..pls provide fiddle

Comment: Can i remove this primer thing and revers thing?

Comment: you can do anything just i want to sort date property ?

Comment: In ascending or descending order?

Comment: you can do in any order than I will reverse that array to make it order way

Comment: Okay and what would you like to do with `-`?

Comment: I just want a array which is sorted by date sorted a array “akritiv__Promise_Date__c”

Comment: I am checking wait for second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler function to achieve the same thing:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3v7ya481187k8gf/a.json?dl=0",
}).done(function (data) {
    var arr;
    arr = JSON.parse(data);
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {

        var _a = a.akritiv__Promise_Date__c;
        var _b = b.akritiv__Promise_Date__c;

        if (_a == "-") _a = 0;
        if (_b == "-") _b = 0;

        return new Date(_a) - new Date(_b); // Ascending order
        // to reverse do return new Date(_b) - new Date(_a);
    });

    // Verify using printing the dates
    [].forEach.call(arr, function (ins) {
        console.log(ins.akritiv__Promise_Date__c);
    });
});
```

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rxaLutgn/16/

Comment: Thanks it is correct answer ...if I want to change the order then I reverse the  array or is there any other better way..!1

Comment: Dude i have mentioned it in the comment.. `// to reverse do return new Date(_b) - new Date(_a);`..